# Retrieve particular values from the POST endpoint in Express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have an API definition `/task/{activityId}?status={status} ( method = POST)`

`Input -> activityId, status`

`Output -> status`

In Express I have written my code like this for debugging purpose -

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");
const axios = require('axios');
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/task/:activityId?status=:status", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var activityId = req.params.activityId;
        var status = req.params.status;
        console.log(status);
        console.log(activityId);
        if (status == "COMPLETE")
            const updateStatus = await pool.query("update public.\"TableOne\" set \"Status\"='COMPLETE' where \"ActivityId\"='" + activityId + "'");
}

    catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("server has started on port 5000");
})
```

I am not able to see the values in console of **activity id** and **status** passed when I am hitting the endpoint from postman with something like this -

[POST] http://hostname:port/task/A1?status=PENDING

What mistake am I making here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get values from parameter, proper way is like this

```
console.log(req.params.status);
```

But secondary parameter named status is stated as querystring parameter, So, you need to fetch like this,

```
console.log(req.query.status);
```

Also, you don’t need to mention status in the code, so, your code to fetch the param should be like this:

```
app.post("/task/:activityId", async (req, res) => {
```

As you can see, I didn’t mention the **status** parameter. Still I will get it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing in my above post. But this doesn't work.

Comment: update answer with a given new answer based on your last comment.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for.

Comment: Welcome @RaghavGupta